# Evaluate $\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{x^{n+2}} c^{1/x} \exp\{-\lambda/x\} \mathrm{dx} $

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, self-learning

I have been trying to evaluate the following integral

> $$\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{x^{n+2}} c^{1/x} \exp\{-\lambda/x\} \mathrm{dx} $$

What I am getting is

> $$\frac{1}{\left(\lambda-logc \right)^{n+1}} \times \Gamma \left( n+1 \right) $$

Could you please check whether this is indeed the correct answer?

Thank you.

Comment: An attempt would be writing the exponential function as a taylor series and use the monotone convergence theorem.

Comment: @Nickolas I've done it differently by change of variables. What I am looking for is a confirmation this is the right answer, whichever way one prefers.

Comment: pardon me, I thought you only knew what the answer was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple substitution $u=\dfrac1x$, coupled with the fact that $c=e^{\ln c}$, should be enough to transform this expression into something more [recognizable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function). Indeed, *Mathematica* confirms your result.

Comment: My thoughts precisely, thank you.